# Error in your SQL syntax, more than likely my Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently getting the error message

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(quantity, product)VALUES ( "number", "text")' at line 1
```

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('../../config/db.php');
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Error with database connection: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO order'.
       '(quantity, product)' .
       'VALUES ( "number", "text")';

mysql_select_db('order');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Is someone able to let me know what I've done wrong and how to correct the error? I'm using  MySQL 5.5.27 and PHP 5.5.

Comment: You need to backquote the tablename, order is reserved word

Comment: Here's a better idea - *change* the table name!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'INSERT INTO  `order` '.
       '(quantity, product)' .
       'VALUES ( "number", "text")';
```

use  blockquotes **`**  as escape char for using reserve words like **order**

Answer (score -2):

In sql for string values use single quotes, not double. So let's try like this:

```php
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO order'.
   '(quantity, product)'.
   'VALUES ( \'number\', \'text\')';
```

or like this

```php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO order".
   "(quantity, product)".
   "VALUES ( 'number', 'text')";
```

Secondly if the type of 'quantity' is numerical, pass a numerical value there:

```php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO order".
   "(quantity, product)".
   "VALUES ( 100500, 'text')";
```

Comment: in MySQL both double or single quotes can hold strings

Comment: the ting is not only in mysql here